# GCS file locking query

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We are using GCS (google cloud storage) and I am wondering if the methods described in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage using open/close lock the file from other things accessing it during the operations?

I am a novice and currently the first method I found is using the download and upload as string functions in `import cloudstorage as gcs`

like...

```
current_details = json.loads(device_blob.download_as_string().decode('utf-8'))
LOGGER.info(current_details)
current_details.update(details)
device_blob.upload_from_string(json.dumps(current_details))
```

But it is obvious here that between the download and upload calls something else could modify the file.

So if the `import cloudstorage as gcs` is the way to go, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by "if the import `cloudstorage as gcs` is the way to go"?

Comment: If using open/close locks the file so other services cannot access it, until it is closed that is.

Answer (score 2):

GCS does not have any locking at all.  If you want to do "read-modify-write" safely, use [Preconditions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_Preconditions) on the upload to make sure that when you write nothing has been changed in the interim (and if it has, re-do the read & modify with the lastest version).

Unfortunately the `cloudstorage` python library has weak support for this, you may need to use [automatically generated "google API library"](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/).

Comment: So even doing like gcs_file = gcs.open(filename, 'w', ...) gcs_file.write('abcde\n') gcs_file.write('f'*1024*4 + '\n') gcs_file.close() during that write, some other service could open the file and write to it at the same time?

Comment: Correct. Nothing is written until you call `close()`, and the last write to close overwrites any before it.

Comment: Don't think of GCS as a filesystem - it is pure object storage and doesn't have many of the behaviours you expect from a file system.